# AWS Toolkit breanstalk deploy on Visual Studio 2017 - 500 Error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

I've recently attempted to reploy a simple .Net Core instance on AWS, using the toolkit, everything suggests it deployed correctly, and the security groups are set correctly...

Yet I can't RDP to the server or view the .net Core ASP web pages... rather I get a 500 error.

For those more experienced, I'm wondering what kind of trouble shooting is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the RDP issue by modifying the Security Settings in the EC2 dashboard - find the instance that was set up by beanstalk, then on the EC2 (not ELB) service page, find the Security Group links, and then View Inbound Rules. If you have the most common problem, ELB created your instance and opened port 80 (HTTP) and port 22 (SSH), but nothing else. Edit the rule for the security group, change the port 22 to SSH, and then you should be able to connect. Note, for me I set the security to MyIP, but it means you can only RDP from your "home" network.

Once you can RDP into the machine, you should be able to get to the logs (inetpub/logs)